# No current through equipotential surfaces

Tags: charge, potential

While solving some simple capacitor problems, I found that certain "excess" capacitors could be removed from a circuit if they're connected across equipotential wires (especially in case of symmetrical circuits), with the logic that **no current flows through equipotential surfaces.**

> WHY?

One of my friends asked me to conduct a thought experiment.

> Keep some water at same levels in 2 tubs. Now connect their bases. Does water flow in between them? Do levels change?

They don't, unless - and I might be wrong - we consider **(random) Brownian motion** of the water molecules. Water (it should, as far as my knowledge goes) flows randomly everywhere, and thus into the *connector pipe that joins two tubs* too, and hence in between the two tubs too.

If all I said was true, water maintains a **dynamic equilibrium** in its level across the two tubs. But nothing says it **doesn't** flow.

> Same way for current. I understand that no work is done when objects are moved across equipotential surfaces. But does that mean, they WON'T go at all by themselves?

P.S. - Is this expulsion of any chance of random movements all because charges are classically *considered* to be not random?

Comment: I've removed a number of comments that were attempting to answer the question and/or responses to them. Please keep in mind that comments should be used for suggesting improvements and requesting clarification on the question, not for answering.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note to myself:

When we are talking about current, as in current doesn't flow across equipotential surfaces, what we mean is **net current.**

No net current flows through equipotential surfaces. This is perfectly comfortable with the idea of a dynamic equilibrium and hence the concept of perpetual random motion. Current does flow, but whatever does is neutralised by an oppositely incoming current. So overall it is zero.

Thanks to @Krishna for the help.

Comment: Are you talking about the case of ideal wires in circuits? If so, then saying there is no net current through the wires is incorrect. Or maybe I don't understand your question.

Comment: I'm talking about ideal wires connected across 2 equipotential surfaces, yes.